# Using Parameters in python luigi

Tags: python, luigi

I have am triggering Luigi via

```
luigi.run(["--local-scheduler"], main_task_cls=Test(Server = ActiveServer, Database = DB))
```

and in my class I have:

```
class Test(luigi.Task):

    Database = luigi.Parameter()
    Server = luigi.Parameter()
```

but the task test can't seem to parse the parameters that I'm feeding it properly?

I am getting:

```
MissingParameterException: No value for 'Server' (--Server) submitted and no default value has been assigned.
```

Comment: Did @Samuel-Lampa answer your question?

Comment: In case someone comes across to run luigi from python run time it's `luigi.build([Test('db','svr')], local_scheduler=True)` see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876861/how-to-use-parameters-in-python-luigi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876861/how-to-use-parameters-in-python-luigi)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, you can not send the parameters through the `main_task_cls` argument, only the class itself. Parameters could instead be sent via the `cmdline_args` argument, like so:

```
luigi.run(
    cmdline_args=["--local-scheduler",
                  "--server=ActiveServer",
                  "--database=DB"], 
    main_task_cls=Test)
```

Note also that there is the `local_scheduler` keyword argument to `luigi.run()` that you can use instead of sending `--local-scheduler` through the `cmdline_args` argument, so you get:

```
luigi.run(
    cmdline_args=["--Server=ActiveServer",
                  "--Database=DB"], 
    main_task_cls=Test
    local_scheduler=True)
```