# How to use Parameters in Python Luigi

Tags: python, luigi

How do I pass in parameters to Luigi? if I have a python file called FileFinder.py with a class named getFIles:

`class getFiles(luigi.Task):`

and I want to pass in a directory to this class such as:

`C://Documents//fileName`

and then use this parameter in my run method

`def run(self):`

how do I run this in command line and add the parameter for use in my code? I am accustomed to running this file in command line like this:

`python FileFinder.py getFiles --local-scheduler`

What do I add to my code to use a parameter, and how do I add that parameter to the command line argument?

Also, as an extension of this question, how would I use multiple arguments? or arguments of different data types such as strings or lists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have already figured out, you can pass arguments to luigi via

```
--param-name param-value
```

in the command line. Inside your code, you have to declare these variables by instantiating the `Parameter` class or one of it's subclasses. The subclasses are used to tell luigi if the variable has a data-type that is not string. Here is an example which uses two command line arguments, one `Int` and one `List`:

```
import luigi

class testClass(luigi.Task):
  int_var = luigi.IntParameter()
  list_var = luigi.ListParameter()

  def run(self):
      print('Integer Param + 1 = %i' % (self.int_var + 1))

      list_var = list(self.list_var)
      list_var.append('new_elem')
      print('List Param with added element: ' + str(list_var))
```

Note that ListParams actually get converted to tuples by luigi, so if you want to do list operations on them, you have to convert them back first (This is a [known issue](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/859), but doesn't look like it will be fixed soon).

You can invoke the above module from the command line like this (i have saved the code as a file called "testmodule.py" and made the call from inside the same directory):

```
luigi --module testmodule testClass --int-var 3 --list-var '[1,2,3]'  --local-scheduler
```

Note here that for variables containing a `_`, this has to be replaced by `-`.
The call yields (along with many status messages):

```
Integer Param + 1 = 4
List Param with added element: [1, 2, 3, 'new_elem']
```

Comment: Can you describe what making a module out of the code means? I don't understand what my_module is or how to run the code that way along with other non-list parameters, because I would like to be able to use both single string parameters and list parameters

Comment: The module stuff was not nessessary to answer your question, so i removed it from my answer. The updated answer should cover the things you need.

Comment: Is there are way to run this without the command line args? I'm calling luigi from inside python code and have a list object I would like to pass in. Seems I can do something like `testClass(1,[1,2]).run()` but not sure if that's best.

Comment: Nvm answered my own question. In case someone comes across it's `luigi.build([MyTask([1,2])], local_scheduler=True)`

Answer (score 3):

So I think this works, in the code I added:

```
fileName = luigi.Parameter()
```

if i run this in the command line:

```
python FileFinder.py getFiles --local-scheduler --getFiles-fileName C://Documents//fileName
```

but if anyone has any advice on parameters of different types and how to use them, especially numbers and lists, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Toterich's answer.
While passing a list of string arguments as a ListParameter():

```
python file_name.py --local-scheduler TaskName --arg '["a","b"]'
```

The string arguments must be enclosed in double-quotes and not single quotes otherwise it'll give a JSONParsing error.